# Loop through folder python

Tags: python, loops, scikit-image

Basically I have 4 subfolders in my directory, and these are present in an array with the following structure:

> path_list = [path1, path2, path3, path4]

When I run this code, I can scan all files in one of the folders.

```
for file_name in os.listdir(path_list[2]): 
    full_path = os.path.join(path_list[2], file_name)
    ...
    new_sub = os.path.join(new_path, subdir_list[2])
    final_path = os.path.join(new_sub, file_name)
    imsave(final_path, img_norm)
```

I would like to find a way for the loop to scan the folder and once it has finished, an `i++` occurred in `path_list[i]` and `subdir_list[i]` which it could change the value of the path. The loop should stop when it have scanned and modified all the files in the 4 folders.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the entire thing in a for loop.

```
path_list = [path1, path2, path3]
subdir_list = [subdir1, subdir2, subdir3]
for i, _path in enumerate(path_list):
    for file_name in os.listdir(_path): 
        full_path = os.path.join(_path, file_name)
        ...
        new_sub = os.path.join(new_path, subdir_list[i])
        final_path = os.path.join(new_sub, file_name)
        imsave(final_path, img_norm)
```

Comment: Thank you, but when i run the script, i get the following error, maybe because of the "for i," : [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Comment: If i leave only the following part: "for _path in enumerate(path_list):
    for file_name in os.listdir(_path):" i get this error: TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not tuple

Comment: `enumerate()` returns a tuple; that is why the code should be `for i, _path in enumerate(path_list)`. Your permission denied error is because your operating system is refusing to let you do whatever file manipulations you'd like to do.